# Why doesn't the constructor update class variables?

Tags: angular, constructor, model

On my Roles component, the following line works well:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rolesFromSugar = this.sugarService.getRolesFromSugar();
  }
```

and my service looks like this

```
  public getRolesFromSugar(): Role[] {
    this.getData("roles")
    .subscribe((roles) => {
      roles.data.forEach((role) => {
        this.roleList.push(new Role(role));
      });
    });

    return this.roleList;
  }

  private getData(item: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.endPoint + `${item}`);
  }
```

And my Role looks like this:

```
import { Model } from "./model";

export class Role extends Model {
  public type: string = "users";
  public id: string;
  public name: string;
  public description: string;

  constructor(data?: any) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export abstract class Model {

  public constructor(data?: any) {
    const self = this;

    if (undefined !== data && null !== data) {
      for (const prop in data) {
        if ("attributes" !== prop) {
          if (typeof data[prop] !== "function") {
            self[prop] = data[prop];
          }
        }
      }

      if (undefined !== data.attributes && null !== data.attributes) {
        for (const prop in data.attributes) {
          if (typeof data.attributes[prop] !== "function") {
            self[prop] = data.attributes[prop];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

This works with no issue and I can see everything on my component.

But when it comes to the User model, the props just won't update:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usersFromSugar = this.sugarService.getUsersFromSugar();
  }

  public getUsersFromSugar(): User[] {
    this.getData("users")
    .subscribe((users) => {
      users.data.forEach((user) => {
        this.userList.push(new User(user));
      });
      console.log("USERLIST", this.userList);
    });

    return this.userList;
  }


import { Model } from "./model";

export class User extends Model {
  public type: string = null;
  public id: string = null;
  public userName: string = null;
  public salutation: string = "Mrs.";
  public lastName: string = null;
  public firstName: string = null;
  public phoneHome: string = null;
  public phoneMobile: string = null;
  public phoneWork: string = null;
  public phoneOther: string = null;
  public phoneFax: string = null;
  public phoneAsterisk: string = null;
  public email: string = null;
  public status: string = "Active";
  public employeeStatus: string = "Active";
  public title: string = null;
  public managerId: string = null;
  public department: string = null;
  public officeId: string = null;
  public teamId: string = null;
  public tourplanID: string = null;
  public swClickToCall: boolean = false;
  public swCallNotification: boolean = false;
  public codeSonGalileo: string = null;

  public swPhoneNumber: string = null;
  public swExtension: string = null;
  public swTelephony: boolean = false;
  public inheritsPreferencesFrom: string = "user_default";
  public roleId: string = null;
  public serviceId: string = null;
  public functionId: string = null;
  public destinations: string[] = [];
  public ggOrganisationId: string = null;
  public ggGroups: string = null;
  public isAdmin: number = 0;
  public apiPortalUser: number = 0;
  public assignationNotification: number = 0;
  public userGroup: number = 0;
  public defaultTeams: number = 1;
  public leadsMin: number = 15;
  public leadsMax: number = 45;

  public constructor(data?: any) {

    super(data);
    console.log("data passed to super, ", data);
  }
}
```

When I console.log(self[prop]), I see it all right. But then the variables just don't update and keep their default values.
We are running Angular 4 in a Docker

For all intents and purposes, this is what the data looks like:

```
{
"data": [
{
"type": "users",
"id": "4ab50c2e-fce7-8385-2e9f-5c2e85737c1a",
"attributes": {
"id": "4ab50c2e-fce7-8385-2e9f-5c2e85737c1a",
"userName": "asdasdsad",
"salutation": "",
"lastName": "asdasdsadsad",
"firstName": "asdasdsad",
"phoneHome": null,
"phoneMobile": null,
"phoneWork": "0123456789",
"phoneOther": null,
"phoneFax": null,
"phoneAsterisk": "2083",
"email": null,
"status": "Active",
"employeeStatus": "Active",
"title": null,
"managerId": "",
"department": "Ventes",
"officeId": "1009",
"teamId": "",
"tourplanID": "asdasd",
"swClickToCall": "1",
"swCallNotification": "1",
"codeSonGalileo": ""
}
},
{
"type": "users",
"id": "asdasdasdsadsad",
"attributes": {
"id": "asdsadsadsa",
"userName": "asdsadasd",
"salutation": "Mr.",
"lastName": "asdsa asdsad",
"firstName": "asdsad",
"phoneHome": null,
"phoneMobile": null,
"phoneWork": "018888888",
"phoneOther": null,
"phoneFax": null,
"phoneAsterisk": "2272",
"email": null,
"status": "Active",
"employeeStatus": "Active",
"title": null,
"managerId": "8aba3fff-7c33-f4ea-283d-57d1e94e6627",
"department": "Ventes",
"officeId": "1009",
"teamId": "Iroquois",
"tourplanID": "asdasd",
"swClickToCall": "1",
"swCallNotification": "1",
"codeSonGalileo": ""
}
},
```

If the constructor could update the User model just like it updates the Role model variables, then my component could display the data fetched from the API. Thank you a lot in advance.

EDIT: I tried this and I still have the same result:

```
  public getUserPromiseFromSugar(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.getData("users")
    .map((users) => users.data)
    .toPromise();
  }

  public getUsersFromSugar(): User[] {
    this.getUserPromiseFromSugar()
    .then((users) => users.forEach((user) => this.userList.push(new User(user))))
    .then((data) => console.log("promise over", this.userList));

    setInterval(() => console.log("this userlist", this.userList), 1000);

    return this.userList;
  }
```

Comment: You return `return this.roleList;`before subscription has been received as is not surely executed before returning.

Comment: well, I think it's not a problem because he returned a reference

Comment: will you able to setInterval and run console.log(this.usersFromSugar), and to see if the data hasn't been shown or the data is wrong?

Comment: @Bernhard I did as you said but my userList stays with default properties - check the edit

Comment: @陈杨华 I did that and my userList stays with default properties - check the edit

Comment: Maybe you change this.userlist  somewhere after get it. Maybe you are using extra decorator like @input or binded by ngmodel.you can add 'debugger;' to your code and open developer mode ,it helps you debugging. step by step

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the default values. For some reason, the default values will override the arguments passed in the constructor.

I removed the default values and the constructor did the job. Now I'm trying to put them back without overriding the arguments.