# Angular forms: First input element does not reflect FormBuilder value

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I am fairly new to Angular, so bear with me if my question is a little silly.

So, I have this reactive form that receives data for edit from my controller, it works but same time it is buggy.

**Controller:**

```
  myForm:any;
  expense:any;

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder, private exService: ExpenselistService, private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(res => {
      this.exService.load('expdata', res['token']).subscribe(data => {
        this.expense = data;
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
          extitle:  [this.expense.title, [Validators.required]],
          examount: [this.expense.amount, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]],
          extype:   [this.expense.type, [Validators.required]]
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

**View:**

```html
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="doSubmit()">
    <div class="form-floating mb-2">
      <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" formControlName="extitle" placeholder="Title">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating mb-2">
      <input type="number" id="amount" class="form-control" formControlName="examount" placeholder="Amount">
      <label for="amount">Amount</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2 text-center">
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" checked formControlName="extype" id="exdebit" value="debit">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exdebit">Debit</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="extype" id="excredit" value="credit">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="excredit">Credit</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success py-2 px-3 rounded-5">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The issue is, the **title** does not reflect the value from the controller when the edit is being made, it defaults to empty meanwhile the **amount** and **type** both work as expected and I have no idea why, when I console.log the data it shows the expected data with the title and everything else. Then I duplicated the title element as-is without changing anything, the duplicate had a value while the topmost input is still empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried initialising your `FormGroup` synchronously inside the constructor and then using `this.myForm.patchValue()` to set the values whenever your data is ready?

Comment: Nope, I have no idea how that works, maybe explain it further. But notice that the initialization of the form fields itself is in the constructor, am I supposed to have done it elsewhere?

Comment: You can try removing the default values. I saw a similar issue and what worked for him was to remove the default values. For some reason the default values override the arguments passed in the constructor.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54416975/why-doesnt-the-constructor-update-class-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your code like this:

```
  myForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
          extitle:  ['', [Validators.required]],
          examount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]],
          extype:   ['', [Validators.required]]
        });

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder, private exService: ExpenselistService, private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(res => {
      this.exService.load('expdata', res['token']).subscribe(data => {
        this.myForm.patchValue({extitle: data.title, examount: data.amount,extype: data.type})
      });
    });
  }
```

You should initialize the form only once and afterwards just patch the value.

To access the data just fetch it from the from like this: `this.myForm.getRawValue()`

Comment: I finally figured out a solution that worked and the cause of the error was linked to execution time and absence of the initialization during that time. But I am marking this solution as correct cos it cut down on my junky solution, it's straight forward and is more legible. Thanks a lot